# Is an asynchronous class in Javascript a good idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm looking to create a class which retrieves information from a database and sets user variables appropriately.

My issue is that, the database API I am using is asynchronous and this becomes an issue because the class becomes accessible before it has been 'fully constructed' (that is to say the constructor function has returned).

**Desired synchronous approach**

```
class User{
    constructor(sql){
        this.name = Database.selectQuery(sql);
    }
}
var x = new User(statement);
console.log(x.name); // returns name
```

**Current asynchronous approach**

```
class User{
    constructor(sql){
        Database.selectQuery(sql, this, function(data, obj){
            obj.name = data;
        });
    }
} 
var x = new User(statement);
console.log(x.name); // returns undefined
```

I'm aware I can add a callback to my constructor in order to make it work asynchronously but is this a good idea?

Comment: If you are writing code in node, you are writing async code. You are using either callbacks or promises.

Comment: Welcome to "callback hell".

Answer (score 2):

You will quickly find that all async operations must be able to communicate to the caller when they are complete because they complete some indeterminate time in the future.  This means they either need to accept a callback or they need to return a promise.

While you can pass a callback to a constructor, you can't return a promise from a constructor (it has to return the object) so it is generally not recommended to put an async operation in the constructor.  Instead, the code flow by the caller is more straightforward if you construct the object and THEN call an async method on the object.

As your example clearly shows, you have created no way for the caller of your `User` object to know when the async operation in the constructor is complete and thus, there is no reliable way for the caller to use the results of that operation.  That's not just a bad idea, but a complete non-starter.  You would be forcing the caller to set some sort of timeout and either guess when the async operation is done or poll looking for completion - both bad things to do.

The more common design approach is to separate out the async operation into a method:

```
class User{
    constructor(){ }

    select(sql, callback) {
        Database.selectQuery(sql, this, function(data, obj){
            obj.name = data;
            callback();
        });
    }

} 

var x = new User();
x.select(statement, function() {
    console.log(x.name);
});
```

The modern way of designing async interfaces is really moving to promises now and they offer significant advantages in error handling and in coordinating multiple async operations so that would really be my recommendation for an interface.

Your interface above probably also needs error handling.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please ignore the lack of error handling - the code supplied is simplified to express my issue efficiently. 

To further this discussion, whether I create the asynchronous constructor or a separate function, I still have the same issue. I would have to put my WHOLE program code in the callback. 

The user class is supposed to be a cached version of what is stored on the server and will be passed to the view. I cant see how I would pass it to the view if I am using a callback.

Comment: @Andy - welcome to async programming in node.js.  Yes, you must put all code that wants to use the results of your async operation in the completion callback or in a function that is called from there.  That's how async programming works in Javascript - period.  You will need to get use to this concept.  Your design probably needs to be tweaked so an object is not trying to initialize itself with an async operation as that design pattern just has troubles.